# Laravel 5.4 JWT authentication not working with curl

Tags: php, authentication, curl

i'm using **tymondesigns/jwt-auth** package and i'm having a very strange issue when trying to authenticate an user using curl. **JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)** always returns false even though the credentials are corrent cause. I tested it using the HttpRequester addon on firefox and it works with it, it returns the token, why it wouldn't work with curl?

this is the authentication code

```
try {
        //i checked that the credentials are correctly received at this point, even when using curl
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {                
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
    }
} catch (JWTException $e) { }
```

have you seen anything similar before?

This is the curl i'm using in the client

```
   //set headers
    $headers=[];
    if($method == 'post'){
        $headers[]= 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';            
    }
    else{
        $headers[]='Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8';
    }

    if(isset($apiToken) && $apiToken != ''){
        $headers[]= 'Authorization: Bearer '.$apiToken;
    }

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    if($method == 'post'){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        if(isset($parameters)){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parameters));
        }
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);

    $result['content'] = curl_exec($ch);
```

the **$parameters** array only contains email and password, as far as i understand **JWTAuth::attempt()** only needs those to work (and as a matter of fact it does work from Firefox HttpRequester) perhaps it has to do with the laravel's guard system or something?

**Update:**

I've tested with GET method instead of POST but i got the same result, it is not authorizing neither

I've just tested it using the command line curl and it is working, this is what i did:

`curl -X GET 'http://myapi.cc/api/auth?email=XXXXXX&password=XXXXX'`

Aparently it is something with the **PHP Curl** that is causing this issue

Comment: If you think that the curl request is the issue, you should show that code. What does `$credentials` contain?

Comment: if i do Log::info($credentials) it shows this array: local.INFO: array (
  'email' => '[the user mail]',
  'password' => '[the user pwd]',
)